# How to stop websites telling me "Found the internet!" or "Your internet connection has been restored"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, web

I have yet to find out how to disable this new web 2.0+ irritant. What business is it of the website vendor, whether **it** thinks **my** computer is having trouble with the internet or not?

I've tried to find the root cause of this and have come up dry. I'm guessing, either the browser (Chrome) is notifying the web apps, or they are polling constantly to detect outages lasting 1-2 seconds.

MacOS 11/12 on Macbook Air/Pro on a home WIFI of Time Capsule. Two wifi networks, same ESSID, one of them 5GHz. My wife, working on Microsoft Windows has no complaints. Neither does my phone (iOS, Safari).

I'd love to know if

- there is something in my browser I can disable
- there is some pattern in adblock etc. that I can add

Comment: Facebook does this if the line drops. I've never seen any other site do it. Try Safari to eliminate Chrome as the suspect.

Comment: Note that this functionality is likely implemented via javascript, which executes client side in your browser process, so it is actually your computer that is telling you that, not "It" (the remote application).

Comment: @Tetsujin Reddit is another culprit.

Comment: @Op, this is just a design pattern for modern web applications. in the old days, if you wanted to go to the next page of superuser questions, or sort them, or see new questions, you would have to refresh the entire page. that takes time, processing on both server and client, and causes the entire screen to update (the used to call it "flicker") in order to get any change to the page. Then came AJAX, a programming paradigm where bits of the page are updated while running, without re-getting, rendering, and displaying the whole page. so js in your browser is periodically asking for data updates.

Comment: Thank you all. I can see I have phrased my question incorrectly.

Comment: Note: I have updated my question to clarify: I only want to understand this phenomenon well enough to DISABLE it. As my attempts to do so (browser settings, adblock) have been unsuccessful.

Comment: you probably cannot since you did not write the web application. you can probably deny the domain the ability to run javascript, but then their site would probably not work. if you happen to find that on a given app, the domain supplying the javascript is different than the one serving content, then you may get lucky and be able to disable just js from that domain, but this is unlikely. Sorry. this is just not somthing under the users control.

Answer (score 2):

> What business is it of the website vendor, whether it thinks my computer is having trouble with the internet or not?

So website vendors don't get blamed for people's Wi-fi issues.

> or they are polling constantly to detect outages lasting 1-2 seconds.

Most likely.  Javascript code on a website can issue HTTP(S) requests, and if they don't work, they'll generate errors.  Other code can monitor those errors and take action, such as displaying a "Connection error" message.  This may also apply,

Other methods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline) may not be able to 100% confirm Internet connection state.  Not aware of a browser API that directly allows Javascript code to directly get local network information.

Comment: its likely error handling for AJAX services, such that when AJAX update calls fail, the exception handling alerts the user, and perhaps notifies them when the issue is resolved

Comment: @LawrenceC Thank you for your well-worded answer. I actually would like to know how to prevent the display of these events. To answer your question at the end, there is a published API to report offline state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event

Answer (score 2):

You can use adblock or fair adblocker or ghostery

with fair adblocker

- right click and hover over **fair adblock by STANDS**
- click on **Block elements on this page**
- choose that part and **save**

the other extensions with the same way

or you can create your extension that remove that JS code or put it empty or hide that HTML
you can work with this [base template](https://github.com/ewliang/Chrome-Extension-Base-Template) and use this Web APIs :

```
navigator.onLine
addEventListener('offline', (event) => { });
onoffline = (event) => { };
addEventListener('online', (event) => { });
ononline = (event) => { };
```

or create a function

```
function removeupdateIndicator() {
     var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
     if ( status == 'online') {         
     document.getElementById("thatid").style.display = "none";
     }
     if ( status == 'offline') {
     document.getElementById("thatid").style.display = "none";
     }
   }
```

Comment: to any one reading this  i'm not an expert in JS if this function needs some changes you can edit it

Comment: I think the `navigator.online` behavior is a little different than you are thinking so its output and events are probably not the cause of the message. from MDN: "In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. "  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine

Comment: @FrankThomas yeah you are right, but you can say that my answer is more like a workaround that he can work with or recreate his function with until he provide us with more information bcs you see in the function even if true or false he will get the same results ( hiding that popup)

Comment: good point. cheers!